# C++ can't select correct partial template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm having a problem with partial template specialization.

I have this little helper template and partial specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct ctor_std_vector_get
{
    static_assert(false,"ERROR");
};


template<typename T>
struct ctor_std_vector_get<const std::vector<T>>
{
    static const T& get(const T& x){
        return x;
    }
};
```

And then, I use it something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class container
{
    public:

    container(const std::vector<T>& inp):
    {
        alloc();

        for( const T& t : inp){
            const T& x = ctor_std_vector_get<T>::get(t);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I compile, I hit the static_assert, when I want the partial specialization.  I think I've done something wrong, since if the partial specialization was a match, it would be selected before the base template.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
container(const std::vector<T>& inp):
{
    alloc();

    for( const T& t : inp){
        const T& x = ctor_std_vector_get<T>::get(t);
    }
}
```

Let's say you passed a `std::vector<int>` as a parameter to this function.

Therefore, the `T` part, in `const std::vector<T>&` would be `int`. Simple substitution.

Now that we've established that `T` is substituted by `int`, which template do you expect that `ctor_std_vector_get<T>`, or `ctor_std_vector_get<int>` wind up using, the default template, or the specialization?

Comment: thanks for your reply.


The idea I got from reading eg cppreference was that once the base template is found (the one with the static_assert), the compiler looks for (partial?) specializations, of which the the partial specialization that I want is, I think

Comment: Your idea is absolutely 100% correct. And if you try to answer my question, your answer would be: the default template, because the template parameter is `int`, and not `std::vector<int>`, because `T` is `int`.

Comment: Thanks again.  Think i got it, ctor_std_vector_get<const std::vector<T>>.  but now i have a follow up question.  even when this works, i still get the static_assert, but isn't the base template not compiled?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I still get the static_assert". You probably need to post a follow-up question, with your updated code, and a description of the new problem that you're having.